# Application hanging in a web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have an application that users were complaining that it hangs when the user trys to perform a certain action.  I found it that it is hanging in a web service call.  The web service is running on a remote server.  I can't figure out how to debug into the web service through VS when the code is on a remote server.

How do I find out in the web service where exactly the code is hanging?

Comment: do you have access to the web service code?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the source of the web service then you're not going to be able to "debug" it. If you want to try to externally debug it then you can create a page that sends various inputs to it (some that should work, some that should error out, etc). You can then access this page in a browser that has developer tools (I would recommend Firefox w/ Firebug or Google Chrome) and then look at how long the calls are taking. Google Chrome will show you how long it took to send the request, how long it waited, how long it took to receive, etc. If it IS the actually web service and you don't have access to it then it would be odd that you were responsible for fixing this issue. I have a feeling though, if this is a robust web service, you're going to find that you're either having a networking issue or your sending it some invalid input or something along those lines.

If you do have access to the source code then simply run the web service locally and point your local version of the application at the local version of the web service. Any breakpoints you put in the web service will hang the application and you will be able to step through it just like you can non-web-service code.

Answer (score 0):

In your own code, take a look at what is going on with the web service call. e.g Does it throw a fault? Timeout? Does it ever return a successful response? If not, are you sending valid data?

If the web service call is successful but just slow, consider how you might make your application appear to be more responsive. One possibility is to use [Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360).